# Passing an empty set to a function with type const std::set<std::string>& my_set_that_can_be_empty

Tags: c++, std, pybind11

I'm trying to pass a set of strings to a c++ function. That works fine. However, in some cases the set is empty and I get a type error.

It may be that this is a c++ problem or it may also be that it is connected that I call the function fro python via pybind11.

Any suggestions on how this can be elegantly solved are highly appreciated.

I have posted an example here:

https://github.com/dickreuter/neuron_poker/blob/master/tests/test_montecarlo_cpp.py#L44

```
def test_montecarlo4():
    """Montecarlo test"""
    my_cards = {'AS', 'KS'}
    cards_on_table = {}
    expected_results = 66.1 + 1.6
    players = 2
    _runner(my_cards, cards_on_table, players, expected_results)


def _runner(my_cards, cards_on_table, players, expected_result):
    """Montecarlo test"""
    # if len(cards_on_table) < 3:
    #     cards_on_table = {'null'}
    equity = calculator.montecarlo(my_cards, cards_on_table, players, 5000)
    assert equity == pytest.approx(expected_result, abs=1)
```

calling
https://github.com/dickreuter/neuron_poker/blob/master/tools/Montecarlo.cpp#L266

```
double montecarlo(const std::set<std::string>& my_cards, const std::set<std::string>& cards_on_table, const int number_of_players, const int iterations) {
```

resulting in:

```
E       TypeError: montecarlo(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
E           1. (arg0: Set[str], arg1: Set[str], arg2: int, arg3: int) -> float
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve] with your code and errors you get.

Comment: For C++ the type is independent of the state of the object, so I would assume it is a pybind-problem. But you should really add an [mre] and the complete error. It is not even clear to me if this is a compile-time error or not.

Comment: added an example (not exactly as minimal as it should be) but it should illustrate the problem